# Grabbing the address of the pointer variable itself, instead of the address that we are pointing to, in C/C++?

Tags: c++

Let's consider I have the following `x` pointer variable in my function:

```
  int* x = new int { 666 };
```

I know I can print its value by using the `*` operator:

```
std::cout << *x << std::endl;
```

And that I can even print the address of where the `666` is being stored on the heap, like this:

```
std::cout << (uint64_t)x << std::endl;
```

But what I'd like to know is on whether it's also possible to grab the address of the `x` variable itself, that is, the address of the region of memory in the stack containing the pointer to the heap int containing `666`?

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing special about pointers. If `e` is an expression of type `T`, `&e` is a `T*`.

Comment: You don't need casting to `uint64_t` to print a pointer; it's better to print it as-is: `std::cout << x` — it prints the pointer in hexadecimal form, which is considered more standard.

Comment: And if you want to cast to an integer, prefer `std::uintptr_t`, which is guaranteed to have the right bit width.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie A typo. :(

Comment: @anatolyg -- with the caution that a pointer to `char` will need a cast; otherwise it will display the C-style string that the pointer points at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use another &

```
std::cout << (uint64_t)&x << std::endl;
```

e.g.:

```
int v = 666; // variable
int * x = &v; // address of variable
int ** p = &x; // address of pointer x
```

and so on

```
int *** pp = &p;
int **** ppp = &pp;
```

and how to access to it:

```
std::cout << ****ppp << " == " << ***pp << " == " 
    << **p << " == " << *x << " == " << v << std::endl;
```